# Null check operator used on a null value for userProvider

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. It is giving me an error saying that I have used null check operator on a null value

Links for reference:
https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/main/lib/widgets/community-chat/community_list_drawer.dart
https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/main/lib/auth/auth_controller.dart

My code:

```
  class CommunityDrawer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CommunityDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider)!;
    final isGuest = !user.isAuthenticated;

  ...

  final userProvider = StateProvider<ChatUserModel?>((ref) => null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the null check operator (!) on the `userProvider` in the `CommunityDrawer` widget, and this is causing the null check operator on a null value error. To handle this try this:

```dart
 final user = ref.watch(userProvider); // <-- Null check operator here
 final isGuest = (!user?.isAuthenticated) ?? true;
```

Comment: I tried doing that. But its giving the error "A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition" on !user?.isAuthenticated

Comment: where are you getting this error?

have you added this `?? true;`

Comment: yess. I did try adding that. I copy pasted the exact same thing you sent...

Comment: where are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the null check error, you should perform a null check before accessing properties or methods on the user variable. You can do this using the null-aware operator (?.)

```
final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
final isGuest = user?.isAuthenticated ?? false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're not using either `user` nor `isGuest` in any of your widgets. You're just passing the value to the `onTap` callback. In that case, you don't need to use `ref.watch` in the `build` method, but instead, use `ref.read` inside the `onTap` callback.

```dart
onTap: () {
  // ...

  final user = ref.read(userProvider); // Just let it nullable
  
  // Check if the value of user is null. This is the case when
  // the user tap the ListTile before the value for user is ready.
  // Just do nothing or for better UX you can make your UI show
  // something else
  if (user == null) return;

  final isGuest = user.isAuthenticated; // Now this isn't nullable
  if (!isGuest) {
    // ...
  }
}
```